# Any chance to trigger a kevent w/o knowing the owning queue? Any Alternatives?

Tags: c++, c, macos, darwin

I need to design a "wait-for-event-objects" thingy that could accept opaque event objects and able to block until one of them is signaled. It should work on MacOS/Linux/Windows. So for Linux/Windows everything is very nice:

1. On Windows I can wrap the native event from `CreateEvent` in my pseudo class and in the class that does the waiting call `WaitForMultipleObjects`.
2. On Linux I can mix `eventfd()` with `poll()/epoll()` and achieve the same.
3. On MacOS I can use `kqueue` and `kevent` with `EVFILT_USER` BUT the issue is that I can not trigger the event without knowing the queue/having added the event to a queue, which is not a problem on Windows/Linux where I can either set the event or write to the descriptor.

My question is, are there any chances that I have missed something and I could actually use `kevent` and trigger it somehow so that when later added to a queue it becomes signalled? I am not talking about writing user space code, which let's say knows that an event has been set without a queue and then just signal it upon addition to a queue, I know that I can do that, but I'd pretty much like to use OS kernel primitives if there are such. Of course this excerpt from the man page:

> EVFILT_USER    Establishes    a user event identified by ident **which is not
>               associated with any kernel mechanism** but is   triggered by
>               user level code.

kind of clears all hopes. Then a follow up question - is there any other MacOS kernel mechanism that behaves similar to events and `eventfd()`?

Comment: Look at [`std::conditional_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I want the abaility to user timers and files in combination with the event objects for waiting as well. With `timerfd` and file handles I can achieve this, so that is why I stated "OS kernel primitives". All the std stuff sadly does not provide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pipe similarly to how you use `eventfd()` on Linux.

You could also use a Mach port and `EVFILT_MACHPORT`.

Comment: I had for some reason missed mach port, since that is a kernel triggered mechanism, it could be what I was looking for, thanks.